# Does libgdx implement the game loop for you?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-loop

Initially, I assumed that the developer has to implement the game loop because libgdx is a library - not an engine. But then I found out that [Graphics](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html) has `getDeltaTime()` and `getRawDeltaTime()` so I assume that the game loop is already implemented.

If it is implemented, could someone explain what method libgdx uses? I'm mainly referring to this [article](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/). My guess is that it uses a semi-fixed time step? If that's the case, then why might `getDeltaTime()` "be smoothed over n frames?" How exactly is `getDeltaTime()` smoothed?

If the game loop is not implemented, what is the purpose of `getDeltaTime()` when you have `getRawDeltaTime()`?

Comment: This doesn't answer all of your question, but libGDX implements a render() loop for its rendering, and thus you can keep a time variable that you increment inside the `render(delta time)` method of your scene. When it passes your threshold, you can advance your game model and reset the time variable to 0.

Comment: The game loop is your `render()` function you override in your class which extends the `ApplicationAdapter`class. `getDeltaTime()` is used for moving objects according to time elapsed instead of the frame rate which is not guaranteed to be consistent across all devices

Comment: @Shiro Any idea of how `getDeltaTime()` is smoothed?

Comment: Regarding the smoothing used in `getDeltaTime()`, I've found this [thread.](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=558) `getDeltaTime()` seems to actually be an average of delta time values so I'm going to avoid it because it will cause the game to run at a variable/non-constant speed. Instead, I will use `getRawDeltaTime()`.

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX is formally a Framework and does implement the game loop for you. `getDeltaTime()` does smooth out over a number of frames. Instead you could use `getRawDeltaTime()`. I have seen some people get smoother results by capping the framerate to 30/60 instead of using `getDeltaTime`.

Comment: Any idea of how the game loop is implemented? For example: if I maintain 1 FPS for 60 seconds for example, does that mean `getDeltaTime()` and `getRawDeltaTime()` will return 1 second? The reason I ask is because if that's the case, I think I'm just going to replace it with my own game loop.

Comment: @NathanN.Gonzalez What result would you like to get instead of 1 second ? Just do `Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 0.25f)`

Comment: Take a look at what getRawDeltaTime() for [windows/iOS](http://i.gyazo.com/143db0a64e09e2a454378b99238ef076.png) and [android](http://i.gyazo.com/7486f73ff434408a4a598e6078e77c84.png) returns. This is the latest as of now, 1.6.3 release. You should always use `getDeltaTime()`. Otherwise it would have been named `getSmoothDeltaTime()` instead.

Comment: For the android that "mean" was an average of the last [5 frames](http://i.gyazo.com/733e30c883ca59b5c93b657e60b5f6b2.png). Use `getDeltaTime()` and call it a day. LibGDX is a great framework. I doubt that their `getDeltaTime()` function was now well thought out.

Comment: Not sure about the amount of samples it gets smoothed but my guess is that it does return 1 after maintaining 1 FPS for 60 seconds. Smoothing the time over many frames would not give good results because one big frame drop would cause many frames to suffer from that if you use `getDeltaTime()`. I am curious too at the result you want. You can easily create your own smoothing with the `getRawDeltaTime()` by storing n frames and some basic math. I cannot think of a reason to implement your own gameloop just for frame smoothing.